# Php program fetches data from Amazon-simpleDB

Tags: php, android, amazon-simpledb

I am developing a mobile application in android,I use amazon's SDB for storing data, Now I want to write a php program which fetches the data from the SDB  domines and process it.I am new to php,and AWS.What are the steps/procedures to fetch the data from SDB to my php server.
I am manipulating the domines(tables) in SDB through android app.
If any one have idea please help.Thanks in advance
    * how can I establish an http connection between my php server and AWS?
    * how can I fetch data from SDB to my php server?

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a bunch of PHP libraries available for SDB and for AWS. Please have a look at them:

https://code.google.com/archive/p/simpledb-php/

https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/ - has a library for almost all AWS service written by AWS staff.

Comment: I download AWs php sdk ,But I am unaware of how to use it.If you have idea please share it with me.Thanks

Comment: Getting started with PHP SDK - http://aws.amazon.com/articles/4261?_encoding=UTF8&jiveRedirect=1

See if this is useful - http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/index.html#i=AmazonSDB.